# SQL trigger updating table using another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008r2-express

Hi everyone I am still sort of new to SQL, I have a slight problem and maybe someone can help.

I have researched all about triggers and what I read make sense, but I can't get the answer I need from it for some reason so I will explain what I need to do

I have 2 tables `Products`, `LabelPrint`

In `products` there are 5 columns `upc, itemcode, description, price, labelprint`

In `LabelPrint` there are the same columns

What I need is a trigger for when a new item is created or a old item is edited and the column `LabelPrint` is modified to =1 for yes

I need the item in question to be copied over to `labelprint` table

The `label print` table is automatically cleaned of this items after a certain period of time, I just hope someone can give me some help in understanding how I can make this trigger work the way I hope it will

thanks brandon

Comment: First of all: **what database system**, and which version, are you using?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... Stuff like triggers is very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: Is Label Print the name of the table?

Comment: ok as far a database structure i guess i would say im using sql 2008 r2 express structure?  And Vikdor Products and LabelPrint are the table names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertProducts
ON dbo.Products
FOR INSERT
AS 
   INSERT INTO dbo.LabelPrint(upc, itemcode, description, price, labelprint)
      SELECT
         upc, itemcode, description, price, labelprint
      FROM Inserted
      WHERE labelprint = 1
```

This first trigger will fire whenever you insert data into the table `dbo.Products`, and if the `labelprint` column is set to `1`, then those rows are inserted into `dbo.LabelPrint` as well.

The `UPDATE` is a bit trickier:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateProducts
ON dbo.Products
FOR UPDATE
AS 
   INSERT INTO dbo.LabelPrint(upc, itemcode, description, price, labelprint)
      SELECT
         i.upc, i.itemcode, i.description, i.price, i.labelprint
      FROM Inserted i
      INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.itemcode = d.itemcode
      WHERE i.labelprint = 1 AND d.labelprint <> 1
```

Here, I check to see that the row has been updated (not 100% sure if `itemcode` is the best column to use to link the old and new values - adapt as needed if it's not), and I make sure the old value (from the `Deleted` pseudo-table) is not `1` while the new value (from `Inserted`) is `1` - in that case, the column `LabelPrint` has been updated to 1 and that row will be copied into the `LabelPrint` table.

One word of caution: you need to be aware that SQL Server does **not** fire the trigger for each row that is being inserted and/or updated. The trigger will fire **once for each statement** - and that one statement could very well update 50 rows - in that case, the trigger fires **once**, and the pseudo-tables inside the trigger (`Inserted`, `Deleted`) will contain 50 rows each. Just don't ever assume that `Inserted` only ever contains a single row - that assumption would be totally false.

Comment: marc_s the insert works, just tested it, i wrote a php program to insert data into the products table it only add's one product at a time i will test thoroughly, but i believe it will fire correctly, as far as the update i have a question about, it needs to update only when the value for labelprint columns is changed, itemcode will hardly be touched, what will happen is the customer will go into the product and edit it and check mark the label print button and save, what in the update code would you suggest changing? Also maybe this will help, after the customer prints there labels,

Comment: The customer prints there label the label table will be wiped clean and be blank for more input

Comment: @user1617578: try the UPDATE too - I think it should work as you require it to work.

Comment: update too? marc_s dont mean to sound dumb i scanned the page dont no what your talking about

Comment: Thanks marc i got the update working using a variation of your top code